# Problem creating user with email and password with Firebase

Tags: kotlin, firebase-authentication

i'm new to android dev and Kotlin, the code was working fine till i added some validations. I don't know if i have too many if statements or i'm dong the validations all wrong even though they seems to be working. Any help would be appreciated

```
reg.setOnClickListener {
  
    val eml = email.text.toString()
    val passwr = password.text.toString()
    val confirmPsw = confirmPsswrd.text.toString()
    val fName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.f_name).text.toString()
    val lName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.l_name).text.toString()

    if (Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(eml).matches()) {

        if (passwr == confirmPsw && passwr.length >= 4) {

            if (fName != "" || lName != "") {

                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(eml, passwr)
                    .addOnCompleteListener (this) { task ->
                        //if task isn't successful
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {

                            Toast.makeText(
                                this@Register,
                                " Successfully Registered, Login to continue",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this@Register,
                                " Registration error",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                    }

            } else {
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                with(builder)
                {
                    setTitle("Some Fields Were Left Empty!!")
                    setMessage("*Please Enter Your First and Last Name(s)")
                    setPositiveButton(
                        "OK",
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener(function = buttonClick)
                    )
                    show()
                }
            }
        } else if (passwr.length < 4) {
            password.error = "Password must be at least 4 characters long"
            password.requestFocus()
        } else {
            confirmPsswrd.error = "Passwords don't match"
            confirmPsswrd.requestFocus()
        }
    } else {
        email.error = "Please enter a valid Email Address"
        email.requestFocus()
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, new users are being successfully registered into the firebase console with this code. It was working before I added the validations

Comment: Which valication fails?

Comment: that's the thing i'm not sure which one, i get no errors when i run the code but users aren't getting registered

Answer (score 0):

Better do it with your addTextChangedListener

```
private fun passwordchanged(){
    binding.passwordTextForSignUp.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher{
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            val pass = binding.passwordTextForSignUp.text.toString().trim()
            try {
                if (PASSWORD_PATTERN.matcher(pass).matches()){

                }
                else{
                    binding.passwordTextForSignUp.setError("Invalid Password!")
                    binding.passwordTextForSignUpLayout.helperText = "Must be at least one number, at least one special character and at least 8 characters."
                }
            }catch (e : Exception){
                Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity,e.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        }
```

and

```
private val PASSWORD_PATTERN: Pattern = Pattern.compile(
    "^" +  "(?=.*[0-9])" +         //at least 1 digit
            //"(?=.*[a-z])" +         //at least 1 lower case letter
            //"(?=.*[A-Z])" +         //at least 1 upper case letter
            "(?=.*[a-zA-Z])" +  //any letter
            "(?=.*[@#$%^&+=.])" +  //at least 1 special character
            "(?=\\S+$)" +  //no white spaces
            ".{8,}" +  //at least 8 characters
            "$"
)
```

Add Regex under "class SignUpActivity : AppCompatActivity() {"

If you want to check them again later, you can add an if to the button and query whether it is empty.

Comment: thank you, will give this a try

Comment: Don't forget to call this function in "Oncreate" field